# How to solve the matrix from known data?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ is a $n  \times  n$ nonsingular matrix, and $\det \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {{a_{ij}}} & {{a_{ik}}}  \\
   {{a_{lj}}} & {{a_{lk}}}  \\
\end{array}} \right) = {c_{ijkl}}$ for all $i,j,k,l \in \{ 1,2, \cdots n\}$, then can we solve all $a_{ij}$ in terms of $c_{ijkl}$?

Comment: Naively: we have a system of [homogeneous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_polynomial) $n^2$-variate polynomials of the form: $x_i x_j - x_k x_l = c_m.$ And then [Groebner basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faug%C3%A8re_F4_algorithm)..

Comment: Presumably $c_{ijkl} = -c_{ljki} = -c_{ikjl}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For large $n$ it's a highly overdetermined system, with ${n \choose 2}^2$ equations in $n^2$ unknowns. For $n=2$, on the other hand, there's only one nontrivial equation, which just gives you 
the determinant of $A$.  And of course you can multiply the whole matrix by $-1$ without changing any of those determinants.